# Django 'if not' statement is not working properly

Tags: python, django, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make it so that when I am signed in all my drafts show the word DRAFT in red letters so I tried the following

```
<h6 id="date">{% if post.draft %}<div id="draft">DRAFT</div>{% endif %} </h6>
```

but it's not working but if I do

```
<h6 id="date">{% if post.publish %}<div id="draft">DRAFT</div>{% endif %} </h6>
```

it works, and since that worked I figured using 'not' would work

```
<h6 id="date">{% if not post.publish %}<div id="draft">DRAFT</div>{% endif %} </h6>
```

but that didn't work. heres my model

```
class Post(models.Model):

  STATUS_CHOICES = (
     ('draft', 'Draft'),
     ('published', 'Published'),
  )
  title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                          unique_for_date='publish')
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
                            null=True,
                            blank=True,
                            height_field='height_field',
                            width_field='width_field')
  image_url = models.CharField(max_length=500,
                               null=True,
                               blank=True,
                               )
  height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                     null=True,
                                     blank=True,
                                     )
  width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                    null=True,
                                    blank=True,
                                    )
  author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             related_name='blog_posts',
                             null=True,
                             blank=True,)
  body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,)
  publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                            choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                            default='draft')
  video = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  video_path = models.CharField(max_length=320,
                                null=True,
                                blank=True,)

  class Meta:
      ordering = ('-publish',)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.title

  def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('blog:post_detail', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

  objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
  published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager.
  tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
```

and here is the the snippet in my view

```
if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
    object_list = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')
else:
    object_list = Post.published.all().order_by('-id')
```

why is it working with publish but not 'if not post.publish'

Comment: `if post.status == 'draft'`

Comment: @Pythonista I figured it out before I saw this post. But if you make it so I can give you credit I will. Thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your template you should use:

```
{% if post.status == 'draft' %}
```

You have the following field on your model:

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
```

You need only check if the post status' field value is draft or not.

Checking `post.draft` won't work, because there is no field `draft`.